# Can I add a section, suppress it showing when ouputting to pdf, but reference the section number later instead?

Tags: cross-referencing, titles, sections-paragraphs

So I want a centered title page for each chapter of the notes I'm writing using the article class. I've tried this but getting an error:

```
\suppress 

\section{Numerical Analysis Techniques\label{sec:Numerical-Analysis-Techniques}}

\endsuppress
\begin{center}
{\huge{}Chapter \ref{sec:Numerical-Analysis-Techniques}: Numerical
Analysis Techniques}{\huge\par}
\par\end{center}
```

I assume there's a tidier way to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: it is very hard to guess the intent here, how have you defined `\suppress` ?  why can't you simply use a section heading rather than hide the heading and then  typeset a heading "by hand"  (using very strange markup, `{\huge\par}` ??

Comment: report class is more or less identical to article except that it allows `\chapter` so why not use `report` ?

Comment: Thank you. Using report does exactly what I want without any stupid hacky workarounds on my part. Cheers!